# Time reversal symmetry implies that fermions are massless?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, lattice-model

In [TASI Lectures on Emergence of
Supersymmetry, Gauge Theory and String in
Condensed Matter Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5127) some continuous limit of lattice model with fermions considered. And on page 6 there is a statement:

> **The fermions are massless without any fine tuning, which is protected by
> the time reversal symmetry and the inversion symmetry.**

**Why time-reversal symmetry imply that fermions are massless?**

Comment: Not sure I am helping, but is this meant to be specific for 2+1 dimensions?

Comment: @RhoPhi, maybe, this lattice system is 2+1 d. It will be very helpful if in answer some details about dimension will be also presented. I think that this for any odd dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For relativistic fermions in 2+1 and 6+1 (mod 8) dimensions a Dirac mass changes sign under time reversal.  This is because we do usually do time reversal using the matrix ${\mathcal T}$ that obeys
$$
{\mathcal T}\gamma^\mu {\mathcal T}^{-1} = (\gamma^\mu)^T
$$
and setting
$$
{\mathfrak I^{-1}}  \psi(x,t) {\mathfrak I}= \eta_T {\mathcal T}\psi(x,-t).
$$
Here ${\mathfrak I}$ is the antiunitary time reversal operator.

The ${\mathcal T}$   matrix does not exists in 3 and 7 (mod 8) spacetime dimensions but we can still  implement a form of time reversal by using the matrix ${\mathcal C}$ that obeys
$$
{\mathcal C}\gamma^\mu {\mathcal C}^{-1} = -(\gamma^\mu)^T
$$
and setting
$$
{\mathfrak I^{-1}}  \psi(x,t) {\mathfrak I}= \eta_T {\mathcal C}\psi(x,-t).
$$
This does all the usual things that we want from time reversal, but it  flips the sign of $\bar\psi\psi$.  The net reults is that while a mass violates parity ${\mathsf P}$ in any odd space-time dimension, it only violates ${\mathsf T}$ in 3 and 7 (mod 8) dimensions. In 5=1+4 (mod 8) a mass does not violate   ${\mathsf T}$.

Comment: Could you explain, why??? Why there's no such phenomena in 4+1?

Comment: I'll amend my answe

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519265/time-reversal-for-dirac-particles-in-21-or-61-mod-8-spacetime-dimensions

Comment: What is $\eta_T$? Are $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ hermitian?

Comment: $\eta_T$ is a possible phase. The matrices   ${\mathcal T}$ and ${\mathcal C}$ are unitary with symmetry/antisymmetry properties that vary with dimension (mod) (this is one form of of Bott periodicity) . The notes by Hitoshi Muryama at http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf are a good resource.